# gitlab-ci Job failed: exit status 1 with no error

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I'm trying to run njsscan to SAST my code on gitlab-ci. But the results of the job always fail even though there are no errors as shown in the image below.
[image: Error1]

If I run the manual on my server the command runs without any problems in the image below.
[image: Error2]

Is this a bug of gitlab-ci ? or is there a solution I can do? thank you

Comment: There is not enough information about your problem! Please tell us which image and which Node.js version you are using. In Gilab's pipeline, every exit status != 0 is interpreted as abort (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#ignore-non-zero-exit-codes).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using **gitlab-runner 15.3.0** with **docker executor** (docker version is `20.10.17`):

- Job is failing with **RC=1** while running the `before_script` part
- Restarting the Job (without any changes to **code** or **pipeline-definitions**) just succeed in the most cases.

We are using a dozen of runners, but even if a job is restarted on the same runner, it succeeds although it just failed there before.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33152988)